# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`abc_db`.`sales_flat_order_item`, CONSTRAINT `sales_flat_order_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_order` (`entity_id`))

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1.

Comment: I have checked all the solution available here and form other sources,nothing is workng

Comment: When does this error occur? When making changes in the admin? When reindexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add a sales_flat_order_item row without having order_id referencing an existing entity_id from the sales_flat_order table

Comment: Yes I know that,actually, product is being created in both tables succesfuly

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a magento specific question.  Perhaps it is better to ask in the magento stackexchange site.